# C++ (VS2010 &2012): Breakpoint will not be currently be hit in; No symbols have been loaded for this document

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints

I have 4 projects under 1 solution in VS(2012), and I'm using C++. I am getting this error for a couple of days now. I tried all resolutions but didn't get any success. I can debug 3 out of 4 projects but when I try to debug the last project (which is a console application in C++), it gives this error.

I spent lot of hours trying resolve this error.

Please help!!

Thanks.

Comment: Doublecheck that you have configured debug mode for the project.

Comment: So a silly question. Is you're project in question being build with debuggable symbols?

Comment: I did check. it is in debug mode.

Comment: I would think so that the project is build debuggable symbols. How do I double check it tho?

Comment: Are *.pdb files being generated for that project in the Debug folder?

Comment: @Ryan: yes .pdb file is generated in debug folder

Comment: is the function definatly being called ? even in debug mode, functions known not to be called or exported are optimised out.

Comment: Make sure the project you're trying to debug is up to date. If it still doesn't work, try a full clean and rebuild all. Restarting Visual Studio might help.

Comment: @user2035147: the function is being called properly.

Comment: @ryan: i already tried these steps. still no success :\

Comment: Is the function you're trying to debug actually part of a library you're linking with?